# How to make submenu drop down display on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I can not seem to get this right, trying to make the submenu display on hover of parent list items. It keeps displaying some funky way , is there a standard way to do this? Cant seem to get any code adaptations to work with my code.

```
<div id="navBar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Artist</a>
            <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">sub menu item 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">sub menu item 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">sub menu item 3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">sub menu item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Apprentice</a>
            <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">sub menu item 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">sub menu item 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">sub menu item 3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">sub menu item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Store</a>
            <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">sub menu item 1</a></li>    
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 /*navigation bar*/
#navBar {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#navBar ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
} 
#navBar li {
     float: left;
    position:relative;
}
#navBar li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: large;
}
 #navBar li:first-child a {
     border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; 
}
#navBar li a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #9DE4BD;
}
#navBar li ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999;
}
#navBar li:hover > ul  {
 display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  float: none;
  clear: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple example for your ;)
you must set `display:inline-block` for `li` tags and set `position:absolute` for submenu (`ul`) ...

**CSS:**

```
#a{
    width:96%;
    height:600px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#0F0;
    background:url(http://8pic.ir/images/lj80krsorpqzchx6xs8b.jpg);
    opacity:0.8;
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:2%;

}
#nav ul{
    position:relative;
    height:30px;
    list-style:none;
    background:#000;
    padding:0px;
}
#nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
#nav li{
    background:#000;
}
#nav li:hover{
    background:#333;
}

#nav ul li ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
}
#nav ul li ul li{
    display:block;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
#nav a{
    line-height:25px;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:100px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">mobile view</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">categories</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Cat 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Cat 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">contact me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### [Live Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6kf5z88/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:none` and `display:block;` property of CSS to accomplish this. All you need to do is  hide the element usually and on Hover `display:block;` that's it.
By the way there are many tutorials on this topic that can be found on internet so I am adding the link
http://code-tricks.com/simple-css-drop-down-menu/

**EDIT:** You should add classes to your `ul` and then you can target specific `ul` to hide by adding `display:none;` to their CSS property and then on hover of the particular element like `.classname:hover{display:block;}`.

Comment: While the link might be useful, you need to add the relevant parts of the link. Also, you need to include to what elements should he declares those CSS properties and provide solution, otherwise this is nothing but a comment

Comment: @Fabio There is no class declarations on `UL` otherwise I would have added this. Thanks for the suggestion I will try to edit the answer so at least it will be understandable.